# [IntelliJ IDEA][Android Studio] Autocomplete when using semi colon key

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, autocomplete

Resharper has (or had) a feature allowing autocompletion to be triggered when pressing semi colon, so I don't have to press enter to autocomplete and then semi colon.

I can't find how to enable this feature in IntelliJ/Android Studio. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has something similar, but it works for space, dot and semicolon (maybe other characters). Not sure if the behavior can be modified if you want IntelliJ to autocomplete only on semicolon. Here is how you enable it:

- Go to Settings/Editor/General/Code Completion
- Enable *Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.*

---

[image]